# pass hypen in django url

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I'm trying to include all characters including hyphens after /blog/* and pass them to my function in views.py.

This is my URL

```
/blog/entry-id-01
```

I have this in my urls.py

```
urls(r'^blog/(?P<entry>[-\w]+)/$, blog_entry)
```

However, when I load my page. I get the the following error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/entry-id-01
```

My exception value is:

```
blog_pages/articles/entry.html
```

Is there a way to include all characters including hyphens?

edit: added view.py

```
def blog_entry (request, entry):
    return render( request, 'blog_pages/articles/'+entry+'.html')
```

Comment: The problem is a missing template not a reverse match

Comment: The missing template is because the reverse match isn't working. The correct file is entry-id-01.html. However because regex cannot parse hyphens, it is only looking for entry.html

Comment: The regex is fine,  hence why the error shows the url. Your view references a template that it can't find

Comment: Can you please post the actual code that isn't working alongside the full error/exception messages? The `urls.py` line isn't valid python (the string is never terminated). `urls()` instead of `url()` looks suspicious, too.  And finally, a minimal django project with `url(r'^blog/(?P<entry>[-\w]+)/$', blog_entry)` does seem to work fine (on django 1.8.11)

Comment: ya use `def blog_entry (request, **kwargs): entry = kwargs['entry']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using this regex

```
(?P<entry>[^/]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex for matching word characters should be `\w` not `/w` and also you need to specify the name for the named capturing group.

```
url(r'^blog/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/$', blog_entry)
                 ^^   ^
```

Comment: Ah thanks, actually I had it around the right way. I just misspelled it here.

Comment: What is that `r` behind your pattern?

Comment: @Shafizadeh to denote the regex as raw string.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Like Avinash said, it's a raw string, so a control character like `\n` is interpreted literally, and not as a newline. Without this, you'd need to use `\\w` to escape the literal backslash.

Comment: @knbk Yes I got it ... tnx

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, your error has nothing to do with the regex, it would return a NoReverseMatch if that were the case. You can easily prove this by either pointing the url to a different view that does work, or by changing the template file that the view returns to a template that works.

I'd imagine you really dont have a different html template file for every single possible entry

```
'blog_pages/articles/entry-n.html'
```

and its more likely that you have one single html template that all entries should use so you should reference that

```
'blog_pages/articles/entry.html'
```